# How to bind DataTrigger to an Interface property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, datatrigger

I have 4 class which implement my custom ICalendarItem Interface.
That interface has a property called 'Jours'.

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> Jours;
```

My class override that property like this :

```
public override ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> Jours {...}
```

When the Jours.Count goes from 0 to 1, i want to trigger an action so i tried this :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Jours.Count}" Value="1">

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ICalendarItem)Jours.Count}" Value="1">
```

None of these 2 DataTrigger works.

Anyone know how to bind a DataTrigger to an Interface property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to specifically bind to a custom interface property, you need to place place the namespace, interface and property name within parenthesis. You can then reference a sub-property like Count outside of the parenthesis.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ICalendarItem.Jours).Count}" Value="1">
...
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I had to include 'xmlns:ifs="clr-namespace:RessourcesHumaines.Interfaces"' at the top of my dictionnary and reference my property like this <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ifs:ICalendarItem.Jours).Count}" Value="1"> and it worked, ty!

Comment: Correct, I should have specified how to specify the namespace in my answer, but glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

In my test, its work is done well. Please refer to the following code, which probably helps with you.

What this code do is, when `Jours.Count' equals to "3", the Window background gets red color.
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Jours.Count}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ITest test = new TestClass();
        this.DataContext = test;
    }
}

interface ITest
{
    ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> Jours { get; set; }
}

class TestClass : ITest
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        Jours = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>>();
        Jours.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now));
        Jours.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now));
        Jours.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> Jours { get; set; }
}
```